# Warning: preg_match

Tags: php, wordpress

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed:
>   unmatched parentheses at offset 3 in
>   /home/watchit/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 201

for this:

```
if ( preg_match("#^$match#", $request_match, $matches) ||
```

changed to this:

```
if ( preg_match("#^$match#", $request_match, $matches)) ||
```

and got this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in
>   /home/watchit/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 201

Answer (score 4):

```
if ( preg_match("#^".preg_quote($match,'#'),"#", $request_match, $matches) ||
```

Note also I removed the extra `)` before `||`

Comment: if ( preg_match("#^".preg_quote($match,'#'),"#", $request_match, $matches)
      preg_match("#^$match#", urldecode($request_match), $matches) ) {

Comment: got this error for 202 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/watchit/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 202

Comment: @MichaelJohnson: you seem to have forgotten to put the `||` in between them... And you should use the `preg_quote` thingamayig on the second `preg_match` patter too.

Answer (score 1):

Your OR operator ( || ) needs to be part of the if clause, so

```
if ( preg_match("#^$match#", $request_match, $matches)) ||
```

Needs to become

```
if ( preg_match("#^$match#", $request_match, $matches) || your other conditions ){
```

Comment: Actually curious about this down vote, what an i missing that would give such a parse error otherwise?