# wordpress get error with Warning: preg_match()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error with my Wordpress at localhost. It works ok but after I upload I get an error like this :

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at
>   offset 24 in /home/***/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line
>   231
>
> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at
>   offset 24 in /home/***/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line
>   232
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/tokowena/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:231) in
>   /home/***/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1174

at line 213 and 232 i see this :

```
if ( preg_match("#^$match#", $request_match, $matches) ||
    preg_match("#^$match#", urldecode($request_match), $matches) ) {
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 if ( preg_match("#^".preg_quote($match,'#'),"#", $request_match, $matches) ||
```

Note also  remove the extra `)` before `||`

Comment: if remove extra that mean code like this

if ( preg_match("#^".preg_quote($match,'#'),"#", $request_match, $matches ||

Comment: Yes something like this..

if ( preg_match("#^$match#", $request_match, $matches) || your other conditions ){

Comment: This is simmiliar to your issue might be help you ..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060086/warning-preg-match?rq=1

Accept my answer if it helps you.. thnx enjoy

Answer (score 0):

**Do not edit any of the warned files. They are not causing the problem. The main culprit is hidden in your plugins or theme**

Any of your active plugins or theme is causing the error. Try deactivating all plugins first. If it is not solved then deactivate your current theme and active any WordPress default theme. After finding the culprit plugin or theme analyze it for the error. Then you'll find the real reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the Permalink settings.
It was set to Postname. I changed to Custom & %postname% - and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permalink issue. Disable every plugin, set permalink to option ( Ex.: ...?p=123 ) and than re-activate all plugins